# Why can an adventuring druid using Animal Friendship only befriend half as many HD of animals?

Tags: spells, dnd-3e, druid

In the description of the D&D 3.0 druid/ranger spell Animal Friendship, it explains that an adventuring druid can befriend only ½ the maximum amount of HD that a non-adventuring druid could.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, this is a descision by the designers simply because it feels more "realistic". When a druid stays in one place, his animal companions can all have their own nests and burrows near the druids home and wander around nearby most of the time to get their own food and so on. A druid who travels would have to care for all those animals traveling with him, which would be a lot of work.
So it simply feels more realistic that traveling druids have fewer animals around than those who stay at their home place. There isn't really any rules reason why it would have to be that way.